# ADB unable to detect Android Device on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android, adb, ubuntu-18.04

I'm unable to detect android device using:-

```
adb devices
```

Output:-

```
List of devices attached
3536f11e    no permissions (verify udev rules); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]
```

It keeps saying, no permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Kill the existing running instace of adb server by:-

```
adb kill-server
```

Then, run the `adb devices` command with `sudo` as :-

```
sudo adb devices
```

This will start the adb daemon and list your android device without permission error.

Comment: I'm still getting no permission error.

Comment: Did you check the permission pop up on your android device?

Comment: thank you nandal, i forgot to check the pop up on android device. It works fine now

Comment: Does not work for me. The answers in the duplicate questions do not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Check the permission pop up on your android Device.
Accept the permissons on Android Device after running:-

```
sudo adb devices
```

It will list your device with device id along with permissions.